# create a asynchronous function using async await and return a regular object

Tags: c#, webclient, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to build an sdk wrapper that will make all the relevant http calls that need to be made but taking the complexity out of it for the developer using it so I'm trying to build a function that returns a regular object but within that function I want the call and async and wait on httpclient or webclient but I can't figure out how to do this?

All I can see is to have a void function which is no good, or having a Task or Task but that's no good either.

I would like the user to define the function as normal i.e.

```
 MyClss myobject = company.sdk.RequestData("http://....");
```

Is this not possible? I believe that if you use the .Result, it turns the call into an synchronous call which is no good.

Any suggestions or solution? Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: If you are migrating a current code base to this.. do what everyone else (including Microsoft) have done. Create separate `XXXAsync` methods that perform asynchronously. The answer to your question is "No". You cannot have them define their class as normal and hope for it to act like an `async`/`await` combination would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like the user to define the function as normal i.e.
>   MyClss myobject = company.sdk.RequestData("http://....");

The definition of "normal" is changing. In the New World, it is *normal* for asynchronous methods to be called asynchronously (i.e. via `await`).

What you just said is that you want the user to be able to call your asynchronous method synchronously. That is abnormal.

As Simon commented, the correct solution is to provide an asynchronous API for asynchronous methods. Just follow the [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx); all .NET developers will need to learn it sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the "Tap" link. Very clearly explained and makes sense.